# Can't checkout in git due to crlf issue

Tags: git

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cf5d69fd51eb54ca25657f66c3cec4b7

So I try and reset to HEAD, but it says I still have changes and I need to stash them before continuing.

So I stash them but it still says I have these changes I need to stash before I can check out.

I want to reset the files under laravel/ to their original values so that git no longer considers them as modified. However git seems to think they're modified regardless of what I have core.autocrlf set to.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/786578a467521f12a930cda9fbda170e

Comment: Since someone asked, there isn't any permissions issue. I'm able to modify the relevant files in a text editor without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was caused by a .gitattributes file in the laravel subfolder which was forcing autocrlf to input.

This wasn't showing up when I examined the value of autocrlf because it was in a subfolder, which made this issue hard to figure out.

Removing the file fixed this bizarre behavior.